# Adding phpunit/phpunit as a dependency is discouraged in favor of Symfony's PHPUnit Bridge

Tags: symfony, composer, phpunit

есть приложение на [symfony-skeleton](https://github.com/symfony/skeleton)

решил поставить `phpunit` вполне привычным образом `composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit` и столкнулся с возмущением со стороны `symfony`

> Adding phpunit/phpunit as a dependency is discouraged in favor of
>   Symfony's PHPUnit Bridge

и рекомендацией выполнить команду `composer require --dev phpunit` чтоб использовать `symfony phpunit bridge` вместо `phpunit/phpunit`

исходя и всего этого у меня возникло множество вопросов, от конкретных до достаточно обширных. если ответ будет слишком объемным, пожалуйста, просто направьте в нужную сторону, чтоб стало понятно что и где можно почитать, потому что после первичного гугления возникло больше вопросов, чем ответов

собственно, сами вопросы:

1. на сколько оправдано использование `symfony phpunit bridge` вместо нативного `phpunit`, если в перечисленных [здесь](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html) пунктах каких-то явных плюсов для себя не нашел. и нет ли какого-нибудь оверхеда по зависимостям у `symfony phpunit bridge`
2. для чего нужен файл `symfony.lock`, и как `symfony` перехватывает команды `composer'а` и выполняет свою логику. у `composer'а` есть на это какие-то хуки? где лежит код, который запускается?
3. и что такое `symfony recipes` и для чего они нужны

спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Мне думается что symfony phpunit bridge это попросту надстройка над phpunit, которая собственно сама устанавливает и исполняет phpunit. Зачем ? Ну потому что могут, наверное, ну или чтобы избежать ситуации когда phpunit версия одна, а какой нить KernelTestCase, например, уже в эту версию не умеет. Такая история была по-моему при переходе с 5 на 6 версию phpunit (но это не точно). Ну к тому же то что вы еще прочитали в документации.
2. Речь идет о [symfony flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html)  я так подозреваю. Как именно и главное почему flex умеет "перехватывать" , не исключаю что это в коде композера в виде какого то плагина, который отрабатывает когда видит в зависимостях symfony/flex.
3. Рецепты, это попросту последовательность действий, которые выполняет тот или иной бандл при установке . Т.е. вы ставите какой то бандл, и при установке прописываются автоматически конфиги, автоматом добавляется в ядро и т.п. Та же история и в обратную сторону - удалили - бандл за собой почистил, все то что с собой принес. Ну все равно это относится к flex, лучше чем они описывают я уж точно не смогу рассказать ибо не до конца понимаю принцип работы этой всей историей, т.к. мы на флекс так и не переехали.